# Google column chart dashboard

Tags: dashboard, google-visualization

I have this google dashboard column chart:

[image]

My question how can I group the teams. For example hAxes should have only one column that is DOCOPS and Utilisation should be sum of all DOCOPS.

Below is my code:-

```
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
     google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls','corechart']});
      // google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'Utilization',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 1000,
          height: 600
        };

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

     var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Month'
          }
        });

     var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'TeamName',
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Teams', // filter by Team name
            ui: {
                caption: 'Choose a Team',
                sortValues: true,
                allowNone: true,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowTyping: true
            }

        }
     });

     var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 600,
            'height': 400,

            'legend': 'none',
      'hAxis': {
        'title': 'Teams',
        'titleColor':'#cc0000',
                'titleFontSize':20
      },
      'vAxis': {
        'title': 'Utilization',
        'titleColor':'#cc0000',
                'titleFontSize':20

      }
          },
      view:{
      columns:['Group','Utilization']
      }
        });

  /*  var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'pie_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        }); */



        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind([donutRangeSlider, categoryPicker], [columnChart]);

     dashboard.draw(data);
    }


    </script>



<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
    <div><br><br></div>
      <div id="TeamName"></div>

      <div id="chart_div"></div>
      <div id="pie_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Do we have any way to do this? I don't want to modify the json data. some parameter or something that groups the hAxes the team names?

Thanks in advance!

DEMO:-

https://jsfiddle.net/dineshrawat/gy7o2yq4/1/

Comment: See demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/dineshrawat/gy7o2yq4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with grouping with datatable. Add this following listener to your code and also add dataTable:

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'ready',
     function(event) {
         columnChart.setDataTable(google.visualization.data.group(

             table.getDataTable(), [0], [{
                 'column': 5,
                 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum,
                 'type': 'number'
             }]
         ));

         columnChart.draw();
     });

 google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'statechange',

     function(event) {
         columnChart.setDataTable(google.visualization.data.group(
             table.getDataTable(), [0], [{
                 'column': 5,
                 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum,
                 'typdpe': 'number'
             }]
         ));
         columnChart.draw();
     });
 }
```

[**Expected DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/spxyvk2r/)

Also take a look [**Improved Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/8s9wzg1v/) Slider event attached. Created by @Henrik

---

Complete snippet:

```html
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
    <div><br><br></div>
      <div id="TeamName"></div>

      <div id="chart_div"></div>
      <div id="pie_div"></div>
        <div id="table_div"></div>
    </div>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        
// Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
     google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls','corechart']});
      // google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"label":"Group","type":"string"},{"label":"Teams","type":"string"},{"label":"Month","type":"number"},{"label":"Work hours","type":"number"},{"label":"Training hours","type":"number"},{"label":"Utilization","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSDelv"},{"v":7},{"v":2097.26},{"v":0},{"v":0.949158}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSPro"},{"v":4},{"v":168},{"v":0},{"v":0.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSPro"},{"v":5},{"v":166},{"v":112},{"v":0.891026}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSPro"},{"v":6},{"v":228.5},{"v":107},{"v":1.02287}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSPro"},{"v":7},{"v":314.25},{"v":23},{"v":0.900775}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSSppt"},{"v":7},{"v":2552.46},{"v":878.42},{"v":0.815323}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"CSSrch"},{"v":7},{"v":1231.46},{"v":403.81},{"v":0.851703}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"Docstars"},{"v":4},{"v":1548.36},{"v":193.99},{"v":0.951064}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"Docstars"},{"v":5},{"v":1404.41},{"v":192.51},{"v":0.988193}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"Docstars"},{"v":6},{"v":1421.97},{"v":183.93},{"v":0.979207}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"Docstars"},{"v":7},{"v":164.17},{"v":18.17},{"v":0.592013}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"JPMC"},{"v":4},{"v":2887.24},{"v":330.78},{"v":0.867859}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"JPMC"},{"v":5},{"v":2560.9},{"v":1397.62},{"v":0.885179}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"JPMC"},{"v":6},{"v":3248.59},{"v":1931.85},{"v":0.933076}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"JPMC"},{"v":7},{"v":234.52},{"v":142.2},{"v":0.370787}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"XFT"},{"v":4},{"v":1613.74},{"v":114.66},{"v":0.862475}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"XFT"},{"v":5},{"v":1890.48},{"v":69},{"v":0.971964}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"XFT"},{"v":6},{"v":2083.39},{"v":32.52},{"v":1.02515}]},{"c":[{"v":"CLNTSV"},{"v":"XFT"},{"v":7},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"AppSupp"},{"v":4},{"v":202.74},{"v":65.92},{"v":0.233252}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"AppSupp"},{"v":5},{"v":137.89},{"v":67.83},{"v":0.171205}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"AppSupp"},{"v":6},{"v":225.98},{"v":88},{"v":0.266537}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"AppSupp"},{"v":7},{"v":317.36},{"v":113},{"v":0.315513}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DEVQA"},{"v":4},{"v":1727.51},{"v":555.75},{"v":0.975752}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DEVQA"},{"v":5},{"v":1907.48},{"v":85},{"v":0.943409}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DEVQA"},{"v":6},{"v":2152.03},{"v":108.25},{"v":0.987885}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DEVQA"},{"v":7},{"v":2207.88},{"v":61.16},{"v":0.978034}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DPS"},{"v":4},{"v":205.44},{"v":82},{"v":0.865783}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DPS"},{"v":5},{"v":102.93},{"v":132.75},{"v":0.775263}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DPS"},{"v":6},{"v":230.36},{"v":140.09},{"v":0.945026}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"DPS"},{"v":7},{"v":316.99},{"v":23},{"v":0.923886}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"JiraAdmin"},{"v":4},{"v":17.55},{"v":0.58},{"v":0.172996}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"JiraAdmin"},{"v":5},{"v":76.96},{"v":7.83},{"v":0.815288}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"JiraAdmin"},{"v":6},{"v":58.64},{"v":0},{"v":0.523571}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"JiraAdmin"},{"v":7},{"v":63.45},{"v":0},{"v":0.619629}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"NAT"},{"v":4},{"v":276.48},{"v":17.67},{"v":0.90787}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"NAT"},{"v":5},{"v":256.26},{"v":14.33},{"v":0.914155}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"NAT"},{"v":6},{"v":278.43},{"v":5},{"v":0.90843}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"NAT"},{"v":7},{"v":305.96},{"v":10.17},{"v":0.898097}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OPSTESTING"},{"v":5},{"v":252},{"v":32},{"v":0.910256}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OPSTESTING"},{"v":6},{"v":340.5},{"v":5.5},{"v":1.00581}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OPSTESTING"},{"v":7},{"v":246.84},{"v":59.75},{"v":0.98266}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraDev"},{"v":4},{"v":264.42},{"v":47},{"v":0.705208}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraDev"},{"v":5},{"v":266.92},{"v":5.25},{"v":0.81003}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraDev"},{"v":6},{"v":202},{"v":8},{"v":0.815217}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraDev"},{"v":7},{"v":314.57},{"v":1},{"v":0.805026}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraSupp"},{"v":4},{"v":599.21},{"v":164.33},{"v":0.821364}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraSupp"},{"v":5},{"v":530.28},{"v":58.54},{"v":0.591185}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraSupp"},{"v":6},{"v":605.3},{"v":76},{"v":0.665332}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"OraSupp"},{"v":7},{"v":476.86},{"v":32.18},{"v":0.499451}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"WebDev"},{"v":4},{"v":1284.88},{"v":172.34},{"v":0.961227}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"WebDev"},{"v":5},{"v":1498.06},{"v":84.33},{"v":0.981632}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"WebDev"},{"v":6},{"v":1238.35},{"v":178.83},{"v":0.917863}]},{"c":[{"v":"DEVLOP"},{"v":"WebDev"},{"v":7},{"v":1218.26},{"v":360.59},{"v":0.922225}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"CmpAna"},{"v":4},{"v":745.59},{"v":139.16},{"v":0.795639}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"CmpAna"},{"v":5},{"v":806.07},{"v":35.25},{"v":0.808962}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"CmpAna"},{"v":6},{"v":921.2},{"v":35.5},{"v":0.842165}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"CmpAna"},{"v":7},{"v":1031.24},{"v":33.25},{"v":0.887075}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"OpsSupp"},{"v":4},{"v":144.29},{"v":44.42},{"v":1.00914}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"OpsSupp"},{"v":5},{"v":218.52},{"v":53.33},{"v":1.14608}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"OpsSupp"},{"v":6},{"v":207.19},{"v":33.26},{"v":1.01029}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"OpsSupp"},{"v":7},{"v":214.45},{"v":33},{"v":0.806552}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"PPT&SecPro"},{"v":4},{"v":674.52},{"v":143.3},{"v":0.540886}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"PPT&SecPro"},{"v":5},{"v":865.97},{"v":50.6},{"v":0.615974}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"PPT&SecPro"},{"v":6},{"v":874.73},{"v":101.3},{"v":0.601004}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"PPT&SecPro"},{"v":7},{"v":647.69},{"v":88.8},{"v":0.393424}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"prod"},{"v":4},{"v":398.01},{"v":146.42},{"v":0.677152}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"prod"},{"v":5},{"v":372.54},{"v":147.82},{"v":0.62244}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"prod"},{"v":6},{"v":388.74},{"v":165.16},{"v":0.68552}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"prod"},{"v":7},{"v":442.38},{"v":44.91},{"v":0.591371}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"QINT"},{"v":4},{"v":2448.71},{"v":291.03},{"v":0.839381}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"QINT"},{"v":5},{"v":2286.09},{"v":330.49},{"v":0.838647}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"QINT"},{"v":6},{"v":2336.49},{"v":459.6},{"v":0.855597}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"QINT"},{"v":7},{"v":2390.9},{"v":821.27},{"v":0.857036}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"VP&SPPro"},{"v":4},{"v":379.7},{"v":114.3},{"v":0.382353}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"VP&SPPro"},{"v":5},{"v":538.7},{"v":105.6},{"v":0.362782}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"VP&SPPro"},{"v":6},{"v":620.8},{"v":89.4},{"v":0.386819}]},{"c":[{"v":"DOCOPS"},{"v":"VP&SPPro"},{"v":7},{"v":737.8},{"v":52.7},{"v":0.420479}]},{"c":[{"v":"MR"},{"v":"MR"},{"v":5},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"MR"},{"v":"MR"},{"v":6},{"v":297},{"v":207},{"v":0.379518}]},{"c":[{"v":"MR"},{"v":"MR"},{"v":7},{"v":1301.76},{"v":220},{"v":0.932451}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"CLUTCHBOD"},{"v":4},{"v":171},{"v":37.5},{"v":0.461283}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"CLUTCHBOD"},{"v":5},{"v":273.38},{"v":0},{"v":0.813631}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"CLUTCHBOD"},{"v":6},{"v":245.45},{"v":0},{"v":0.829223}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"CLUTCHBOD"},{"v":7},{"v":292.31},{"v":0},{"v":0.86997}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"DBA"},{"v":4},{"v":151.5},{"v":0},{"v":0.901786}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"DBA"},{"v":5},{"v":143.75},{"v":0},{"v":0.945724}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"DBA"},{"v":6},{"v":162.59},{"v":3},{"v":0.940852}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"DBA"},{"v":7},{"v":165.25},{"v":0},{"v":0.898098}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPDEV"},{"v":4},{"v":285.14},{"v":0},{"v":0.963311}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPDEV"},{"v":5},{"v":452.75},{"v":46.66},{"v":0.97541}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPDEV"},{"v":6},{"v":646.68},{"v":13},{"v":0.964444}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPDEV"},{"v":7},{"v":611.54},{"v":2.66},{"v":0.953727}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPSupp"},{"v":4},{"v":203.05},{"v":103.65},{"v":0.878293}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPSupp"},{"v":5},{"v":130.68},{"v":88.94},{"v":0.710285}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPSupp"},{"v":6},{"v":185.11},{"v":101.01},{"v":0.756131}]},{"c":[{"v":"Viewpoint"},{"v":"VPSupp"},{"v":7},{"v":172.78},{"v":80.42},{"v":0.688792}]}]});
          
      var options = {
           title: 'Utilization',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 1000,
          height: 600
        };

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

     var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Month'
          }
        });

     var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'TeamName',
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Teams', // filter by Team name
            ui: {
                caption: 'Choose a Team',
                sortValues: true,
                allowNone: true,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowTyping: true
            }

        }
     });
    
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    'chartType': 'Table',
                    'containerId': 'table_div',
                    'options': {
                        'width': '100%'
                    },
                    'view': {'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
                }); 

     var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'dataTable':google.visualization.data.group(data, [0],
                    [{'column': 5, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]),
          'options': {
            'width': 600,
            'height': 400,

            'legend': 'none',
              'hAxis': {
                'title': 'Teams',
                'titleColor':'#cc0000',
                        'titleFontSize':20
              },
              'vAxis': {
                'title': 'Utilization',
                'titleColor':'#cc0000',
                        'titleFontSize':20

              }
          },
      view:{
      columns:['Group','Utilization']
      }
        });
    
    
    

  /*  var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'pie_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        }); */



        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind([donutRangeSlider, categoryPicker], [table ,columnChart]);
console.log(data)
     dashboard.draw(data);
    
    
     google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'ready',
         function(event) {
             columnChart.setDataTable(google.visualization.data.group(

                 table.getDataTable(), [0], [{
                     'column': 5,
                     'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum,
                     'type': 'number'
                 }]
             ));

             columnChart.draw();
         });

     google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'statechange',

         function(event) {
             columnChart.setDataTable(google.visualization.data.group(
                 table.getDataTable(), [0], [{
                     'column': 5,
                     'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum,
                     'type': 'number'
                 }]
             ));
             columnChart.draw();
         });
    }

    
      </script>
```

Comment: Major flaw with this is that you actually have to draw the table in addition to everything else. You do also redraw the column chart three times for each change. 1) Dashboard update, 2) statechange, 3) ready events.

Comment: Another thing is that this doesn't work with the range slider at all.

[Corrected version](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/8s9wzg1v/)

Comment: Yes i concentrated more on `selectPicker`. Well thanks @HenrikAronsson. Your improvement added in answer.

Comment: Over the charts I've made I have felt that dashboard isn't very worked through, it lacks a lot of possibility to make changes and do everything exactly as you wish.
I usually build the dashboards with event listeners instead, to make sure I can call anything at the time I want.

Check this version:
https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/kej15cr9/4/